# Linux force scripted add-apt-repository

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I have a script that adds a repository with

```
add-apt-repository <repo-info>
```

Is there a way to not prompt the user (such as with a -y flag, though that doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 10.10)

Answer (score 3):

use `add-apt-repository --yes ppa:foo/bar`